# updateOrCreate adds a column to the attributes and origin arrays called 'id' in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

likes table migration code

```
$table->primary(['user_id', 'post_id']);
            $table->foreignId('user_id');
            $table->foreignId('post_id');
            $table->boolean('liked');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('post_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('posts')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unique(['user_id', 'post_id']);
```

likes post eloquent relationship

```
public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
       
    }
```

like function code

```
public function like($user = null, $liked = true)
    {
        $this->likes()->updateOrCreate(
            [
                'user_id' => $user ? $user->id : auth()->id(),
            ],
            [
                'liked' => $liked
            ]
        );

    }
```

when i var_dump updateOrCreate i get:

```
App\Models\Like {#1248 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "likes"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #attributes: array:6 [▼
    "user_id" => 1
    "post_id" => 11
    "liked" => true
    "updated_at" => "2021-07-17 00:16:15"
    "created_at" => "2021-07-17 00:16:15"
    "id" => 0
  ]
  #original: array:6 [▼
    "user_id" => 1
    "post_id" => 11
    "liked" => true
    "updated_at" => "2021-07-17 00:16:15"
    "created_at" => "2021-07-17 00:16:15"
    "id" => 0
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

as you can see there is an id element, i don't know where that came from.

nb.

- when i run the like function first time, it runs correctly (it adds the record to the table)
- when i run it again it fails and it gives me this mysql error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `likes` set `liked` = 1, `likes`.`updated_at` = 2021-07-17 00:20:29 where `id` is null)

edit:

- when i add manually an id element to likes table, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the ID of the actual `like` model that's being created. While you have a relationship between the `user` and `post`. The `like` model that's being created will still need its own `id` used to reference inside eloquent. As is stated in the documentation for primary keys.

> Eloquent will also assume that each model's corresponding database table has a primary key column named id.

Add an id column to your like table will solve the issue, which can be done by using the `id`* method in your migration.

```php
Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
});
```

- [Documentation on the id method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-id)

Comment: yeah thanks, but it's a pivot table. pivot tables don't need an id, right? is this new to laravel? are all tables now need an id even if thery are pivot tables?

Comment: You're not using it as a pivot table though since you're using `updateOrCreate`. Pivot records create a relationship between two tables, in this case, it's a many-to-many relationship, and those use `attach` and `detach` to add those relationships.

Here is a good write-up on [pivot tables](https://gist.github.com/Braunson/8b18b7fc7efd0890136ce5e46452ec72), it's Laravel 6 based but should translate to Laravel 8.